# making a link in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, hyperlink

hi i have 1 row in my mysql table which has got some text (longtext).
I am wanting to manually add a hyperlink to the text in just this one row within the mysql table,

so i just wanted to know is it possible to write/create a hyperlink in a mysql table/text field and if so would it be written in the same way as a html `<a href="`

beacause when i try this the the link isnt produced just the text is / not the acutal link.

can someone please help me or point me in the right direction,

i want to basically add to the text in the mysql table like this:

```
"this is an example of the text in my mysql table" 

"this is an example of the text in my mysql table with me adding a <a href="link.php">click</a>"
```

Comment: How are you actually outputting the table data? (Hint: The fact that the data is being stored/retrieved from a database, is most likely largely irrelevant in this instance.)

Comment: If you want to update the table, just use the UPDATE sql command. 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store a hyperlink in a table like that (that is it won't be a clickable link in the table).

All MySQL can do is store raw text. But if you wanted to show the link on a web page you could just add it as if it where html and it would display it as if it were any other link on the page.